# How to create a custom thread group in jmeter using java?

Tags: java, exception, jmeter

I am using a custom thread group,  *FreeFormArrivalsThreadGroup* provided by blazemeter using *jmeter-plugins-casutg-2.1.jar*.

When I try to create this thread group using java (in the process of creating JMX from java)

```
FreeFormArrivalsThreadGroup freeFormArrivalsThreadGroup = new FreeFormArrivalsThreadGroup();
```

**Code:**

```
package com.create.jmx;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.LoopControlPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.PowerTableModel;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.gui.HttpTestSampleGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestElement;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

import com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.arrivals.FreeFormArrivalsThreadGroup;
import com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.arrivals.FreeFormArrivalsThreadGroupGui;


public class CreateJMX 
{
    final static String JMETER_HOME = "jmeter_home_location"; 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
    {
        try
        {
            //creating a test plan
            TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan();
            testPlan.setName("From Program");
            testPlan.setEnabled(true);
            testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS,
                                    TestPlan.class.getName());
            testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS,
                                    TestPlanGui.class.getName());
            //create a loop controller
            LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
            loopController.setEnabled(true);
            loopController.setLoops(3);
            loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS,
                                        LoopController.class.getName());
            loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS,
                                        LoopControlPanel.class.getName());

            // creating freeFormArrivalsThreadGroup
            FreeFormArrivalsThreadGroup freeFormArrivalsThreadGroup = new FreeFormArrivalsThreadGroup();
            freeFormArrivalsThreadGroup.setName("Free Form Arrivals Thread Group");
            PowerTableModel schedule = new PowerTableModel(new String[]{"Start", "End", "Duration"},
                    new Class[]{Integer.class, Integer.class, Integer.class});
            schedule.addRow(new Object[]{1, 10, 60});
            freeFormArrivalsThreadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
            freeFormArrivalsThreadGroup.setData(schedule);
            freeFormArrivalsThreadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, FreeFormArrivalsThreadGroup.class.getName());
            freeFormArrivalsThreadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, FreeFormArrivalsThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

            //creating HTTP sampler
            HTTPSampler httpSampler = new HTTPSampler();
            httpSampler.setEnabled(true);
            httpSampler.setName("Google");
            httpSampler.setDomain("www.google.com");
            httpSampler.setPath("/");
            httpSampler.setMethod("GET");
            httpSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS,
                    HTTPSampler.class.getName());
            httpSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS,
                    HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());

            HashTree hashTree = new HashTree();

            hashTree.add(testPlan).add(freeFormArrivalsThreadGroup).add(httpSampler);

            JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(JMETER_HOME);
            JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(JMeterUtils.getJMeterBinDir()+"/jmeter.properties");

            SaveService.saveTree(hashTree, new FileOutputStream("ouputfile.jmx"));
        }
        catch(Throwable e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The above line throws an exception. here is the StackTrace

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.<init>(ResultCollector.java:173)
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.<init>(ResultCollector.java:163)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.reporters.FlushingResultCollector.<init>(FlushingResultCollector.java:7)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.AbstractDynamicThreadGroupModel.<init>(AbstractDynamicThreadGroupModel.java:28)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.AbstractDynamicThreadGroup.<init>(AbstractDynamicThreadGroup.java:23)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.arrivals.ArrivalsThreadGroup.<init>(ArrivalsThreadGroup.java:20)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.arrivals.FreeFormArrivalsThreadGroup.<init>(FreeFormArrivalsThreadGroup.java:11)
    at com.create.jmx.CreateJMX.main(CreateJMX.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration.<clinit>(SampleSaveConfiguration.java:296)
    ... 8 more
```

help me out to create Schedule for this plugin using java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This is not a full exception stacktrace, you need to provide **full** output (better with your code listing showing what was prior to line where it failed)
2. The [Free-Form Arrivals Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FreeFormArrivalsThreadGroup/) is provided by `jmeter-plugins-casutg`, not by `jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter`, however you need to have both jars in your project classpath.
3. If you are not able to figure out the way of creating and configuring a JMeter test element programmatically I would suggest considering creating it in GUI mode instead. You will be able to run the existing .jmx test script from Java code more easy than creating it solely using [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/).

Just in case if you still need this, the code should be something like:

```
FreeFormArrivalsThreadGroup freeFormArrivalsThreadGroup = new FreeFormArrivalsThreadGroup();
freeFormArrivalsThreadGroup.setName("Free Form Arrivals Thread Group");
PowerTableModel schedule = new PowerTableModel(new String[]{"Start", "End", "Duration"},
        new Class[]{Integer.class, Integer.class, Integer.class});
schedule.addRow(new Object[]{1, 10, 60});
freeFormArrivalsThreadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
freeFormArrivalsThreadGroup.setData(schedule);
freeFormArrivalsThreadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, FreeFormArrivalsThreadGroup.class.getName());
freeFormArrivalsThreadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, FreeFormArrivalsThreadGroupGui.class.getName());
```

See [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) guide for more information on different ways of launching JMeter tests (including programmatic ones)

Comment: I am getting same exception, after using your sample code also. When creating the object of FreeFormArrivalsThreadGroup, it is throwing _NullPointerException_

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T. Problem is that I configured/added _JMeterUtils_ after the creation of _FreeFormArrivalsThreadGroup_. Just re-arranged the code and its working fine. Accepted the answer.